# Convert a dictionary to a table with column names using base Python without Pandas

Tags: python, dictionary, datatable

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

heights = {'Andy':150, 'Brenda':155, 'Cindy':130}

I want a table with one column of names and one column of heights. I want to keep only the top 2 heights. The end result should look like this:

[image]

Is there a relatively easy way to get such a table in base Python ***without using Pandas***?

Comment: What kind of non-pandas table? You want a string representation of a table, an html table, an ascii table?

Comment: @HenryEcker Is there a non-Pandas table format that contains both string and integers? If so, that's what I want.

Comment: What do you want to do with this structure? Python does not have a `table` data type builtin.

Comment: @HenryEcker I want the final table to show only the top 2 heights, and I want the heights to go from biggest to smallest. If this final table can do both the sorting and the filtering, then that's great. If not, can we try to do these 2 things before creating the table? I don't have any more wishes for the table beyond this.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to be able to filter a dictionary based on values. This problem is not solved with `tables` in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily filter your dictionary to save only the top two values by sorting and slicing.

```py
heights = {'Brenda': 155, 'Cindy': 130, 'Andy': 150}
# Sort Data and Keep Top 2 Results
top_two_heights = sorted(heights.items(), key=lambda v: -v[1])[:2]
print(top_two_heights)
```

Output:

```py
[('Brenda', 155), ('Andy', 150)]
```

Then You can do *anything* you want with your data.

---

If you're comfortable using an external package [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) is a great option.

```py
from tabulate import tabulate

# Header Labels
header_labels = ('Name', 'Height')
heights = {'Andy':150, 'Brenda':155, 'Cindy':130}
# Sort Data and Keep Top 2 Results
top_two_heights = sorted(heights.items(), key=lambda v: -v[1])[:2]

# Use Tabulate to Build Table
print(tabulate(top_two_heights, headers=header_labels, tablefmt='grid'))
```

Output:

```
+--------+----------+
| Name   |   Height |
+========+==========+
| Brenda |      155 |
+--------+----------+
| Andy   |      150 |
+--------+----------+
```

If you wanted no imports you could just loop over and print out the values:

```py
# Header Labels
header_labels = ('Name', 'Height')
heights = {'Andy': 150, 'Brenda': 155, 'Cindy': 130}
# Sort Data and Keep Top 2 Results
top_two_heights = sorted(heights.items(), key=lambda v: -v[1])[:2]

fmt_str = '{:^10}|{:^10}'
print(fmt_str.format(*header_labels))
print('-' * 20)
for (a, b) in top_two_heights:
    print(fmt_str.format(a, b))
```

Output:

```
   Name   |  Height  
--------------------
  Brenda  |   155    
   Andy   |   150
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the dictionary to a CSV file, which would give you the desired output.

```
import csv

heights = {'Andy':150, 'Brenda':155, 'Cindy':130}
last_key = "Cindy"

with open("filename.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["Name", "Height"]) 
    for key, value in heights.items():
        if key == last_key:
            break
        else: 
            writer.writerow([key, value])
```